# React / Next Render Issue, Client and Server Showing Different Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've implemented a section on a webpage that shows an image background and a city name on top of it.

The data file generating the image background and city data is a standard array of objects. The tricky part is that each object's image path must be loaded dynamically to work with Webpack, so the shape looks like this:

```js
// Data
import Copenhagen from "../../public/case-studies/PFB_CR_Case_Copenhagen.jpg";
import NYC from "../../public/case-studies/PFB_CR_Case_NYC.jpg";
import SLO from "../../public/case-studies/PFB_CR_Case_SanLuisObispo.jpg";
import Sevilla from "../../public/case-studies/PFB_CR_Case_Sevilla.jpg";
import DC from "../../public/case-studies/PFB_CR_Case_WashingtonDC.jpg";

export const hpCaseStudies = [
  {
    city: "Copenhagen",
    image: Copenhagen
  },
  {
    city: "New York City",
    image: NYC
  },
  {
    city: "San Luis Obispo",
    image: SLO
  },
  {
    city: "Sevilla",
    image: Sevilla
  },
  {
    city: "Washington",
    image: DC
  }
];
```

In the Next page, I'm implementing like so:

```js
// Component
const Index = () => {
  // Gets a random case study index
  const csi = randomID(hpCaseStudies.length - 1);

  // Shuffles array, sets it into state
  useEffect(() => {
    arrayShuffle(hpCaseStudies);
  }, []);
  const [caseStudies, setCaseStudies] = useState(hpCaseStudies);

  // in render, we should see a random city and background image each pageview
  // but the client and server show different things, resulting in an error
  return (
    <HeaderImage
      source={caseStudies[csi].image}
      tagContent="Case Study"
      tagStatus={true}
    >
      <SecondaryHeading>{caseStudies[csi].city}</SecondaryHeading>
    </HeaderImage>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Sometimes it works when the `city` and `image` are the same but they often fall out of sync. I'm stumbling on React hook lifecycle somewhere in here I'd guess but I'm stumped.

Error (in reference to mismatching `caseStudies.city` values):

```
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "New York City" Client: "Sevilla"
    at h2
    at styled.h2 (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:28:19599)
    at section
    at styled.section (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.browser.esm.js:28:19599)
    at HeaderImage (webpack-internal:///./components/global/header-image.js:74:23)
    at Index (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.js:42:58)
    at App (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_app.js:76:5)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ErrorBoundary.js:23:47)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@next/react-dev-overlay/lib/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:73:23)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:156:5)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:645:24)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:778:24)
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-client-server-mismatch-7wzr4

Reload the sandbox browser with the sandbox console open and you'll see the error. Sometimes the client and server match and display correctly though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const csi = randomID(hpCaseStudies.length - 1);
```

This is the problem. This code runs twice: once on the server, once on the client. And obviously it will mismatch most of the times between this two runs.

You need to generate same ID for both renders. If want to keep server side rendering then you could do it inside `getServerSideProps` for example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      // will be passed to the page component as props
      randomId: randomID(hpCaseStudies.length - 1)
    }, 
  }
}
```

[Or some other server side data fetching method](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

Comment: Smart answer, let me try that out.

Comment: Spot on, thanks for the help @danila. I've only put dynamic data fetches into `getStaticProps` before, not single values you like this.

Comment: `getStaticProps` is also fine for that task, but it will be, well, static, that means id will be generated only once for production build and will be the same every times you refresh that page.